# How can I ignore duplicates from an array

Tags: php

I want my program to ignore duplicates , 
I have used array_unique but I still see duplicates 
I wonder what am doing wrong . 
So I get the phone numbers from the text area then I send them into my php 
Any help will be appreciated 
here is what I have tried .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // click and drop code 
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").click(function(event) {
  var eid = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".text").val($(".text").val() +"\n" + eid);

});
        });
//parents_idcelldrag
    </script>


<form action="index.php" method="post">
 <textarea class="text" name = "cellnumbers" readonly></textarea>
</form>

    <?php 
// I get this
$cellnumbers=(isset($_POST['cellnumbers']))? trim($_POST['cellnumbers']): '';

    $ids = explode("\n", $cellnumbers);
    $cleaned = array_unique($ids);
    foreach($cleaned as $key){
    $final_cell .= $key.',';
    }

    $final_cell= substr($final_cell,0,-1);
    echo $final_cell;
    ?>
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data for `$cellnumbers` please?

Comment: If you are not showing us what the variable `$cellnumbers` contains, this question is unsolvable. This code should work with a normal variable `$cellnumbers`.

Comment: Humphrey, your edit doesn't help much. The contents of `$_POST['cellnumbers']` depends on the data input into the form, which isn't given. What does `$_POST['cellnumbers']` _contain_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be the case if `$ids` have trailing whitespace. Try to trim values before do `array_unique`:

```
$ids = explode("\n", $cellnumbers);
$ids = array_map('trim', $ids);
$cleaned = array_unique($ids);
```

Comment: This is complete speculation.

Comment: How did you figure that out sir , Am so proud of you . We really need people like you in this world . Some people when they fail to answer they just down vote questions , but you totally different and you got it right .

Comment: @humphrey It's just practice, sir. I saw similar issues quite often. I'm glad that my answer was useful.

Comment: Your answer was more than useful , I hope other people benefit from it too

Answer (score 1):

An example would really help here though another way of doing what you want:

```
<?php

$ids = explode("\n", $cellnumbers);

// create an array with the values as the keys and their frequencies as the value
$values_count = array_count_values($ids);
$cleaned = array_keys($values_count);

// glue together the values
$final_cell = implode(',', $cleaned);

// echo the cleaned result
echo $final_cell;
?>
```